# Download file by POST ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an Asp.Net MVC project and in my View this stretch:

```
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            LoadStart();
        },
        complete: function () {
            LoadStop();
        },
        //async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',
        data: JSON.stringify(
            {
                Param1: 1,
                Param2: 2
            }),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#pdf-content").show();
            // Here, fill DIV (pdf-content) with PDF.
        },
        fail: function () {
            alert("Fail");
        }
});
```

In `MyAction`, I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(int Param1, int Param2)
{
    // Code ...

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    outPdf.Save(stream);
    byte[] fileContents = stream.ToArray();

    return File(fileContents, "application/pdf", "myFile.pdf");
}
```

How can I display the PDF in DIV, or even download directly without displaying?

Comment: You cannot download a file using ajax. You need to navigate to a method that returns the file (e.g. you could use `location.href = ....` in your success callback)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for your comment, but do not give me bad news please. I need to use POST type.

Comment: @teovankot Thank you for you comment, but the question referred by you use GET type, but my question type use POST.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues you didn't read it all. It's first POST then GET

Comment: You can post the data to a POST method and save whatever you want, but you then need a GET to a method to download the file.

Comment: You're right! But still it is a little different because I have used MemoryStream instead of a physical file. Unfortunately I cannot save the file to disk.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues you don't need POSt in your case, just use GET

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use POST type. I am generating a report that can send many parameters, and besides a very large URL does not work, it is visually ugly.

Comment: Maybe the answer of Jonathan Amend (not the accepted answer!) to this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post

Comment: @StephenMuecke Your solution is the one that works, post an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the best solution is:
In your POST method save file at the server with unique name (GUID for example) and return this guid to client.

Then make get request, find your file by guid and return file to client and delete it from the server.

And it's very good to create service, that would delete all old files.

Comment: I did something exactly like that. But instead of saving the file on the server, I rescued a byte array in the session.